# how to retrieve pdf files from a an custom file path, which will work perfectly on every version of android?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I want to retrive pdf files from a custom file path and show them all recyclerview.
My Code is Here,

```
public static final File PDF_DIRECTORY =
            new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS + File.separator + "/AppName/");


   File file;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            file = new File(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, "/AppName/");
        } else {
            file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/AppName");
        }

        if (!file.exists()) {
            file.mkdirs();
        }
```

After creating this directory, I have write the code below,

```
private void getPdf(View view) {

        new Thread(() -> {
            PDFModel pdfModel;
            allFiles = PDF_DIRECTORY.listFiles();

            if (allFiles != null) {

                try {

                    Arrays.sort(allFiles, (o1, o2) -> Long.compare(o2.lastModified(), o1.lastModified()));

                    for (File file : allFiles) {
                        if (file.getName().endsWith(".pdf")) {
                            pdfModel = new PDFModel(
                                    file.getAbsolutePath());
                            pdfModelArrayList.add(pdfModel);
                        }
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                handler.post(() -> {
                    if (pdfModelArrayList.size() <= 0) {

} else {
                        //           noResultSwipeImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }

                    pdfAdapter = new PdfAdapter(pdfModelArrayList, view.getContext());
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(pdfAdapter);
                    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
                    pdfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                });

            } else {
                
            }


        }).start();


    }


private void getStatusScope(View view) {


        ContentResolver cr = requireActivity().getContentResolver();
        Uri uri = MediaStore.Files.getContentUri("external");

        String[] projection = {MediaStore.Files.FileColumns._ID, MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.DISPLAY_NAME};
        String selection = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE + "="
                + MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MEDIA_TYPE;
        String[] selectionArgs = null;
        String selectionMimeType = MediaStore.Files.FileColumns.MIME_TYPE + "=?";
        String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension("pdf");
        String[] selectionArgsPdf = new String[]{mimeType};

        Cursor c = cr.query(uri, projection, selectionMimeType, selectionArgsPdf, null);
        if (c != null) {
            while (c.moveToNext()) {
                PDFModel whatsappstatusmodel = new PDFModel(c.getString(0));
                pdfModelArrayList.add(whatsappstatusmodel);
            }
            c.close();
        }

        if (pdfModelArrayList.size() <= 0) {
  //Do Something Here
        } else {
        
            pdfAdapter = new PdfAdapter(pdfModelArrayList, view.getContext());
            recyclerView.setAdapter(pdfAdapter);
            recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            pdfAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }
```

But this code does not work! This code returns a zero-item array list, actually, I'm a little confused about android scope storage, can anyone give me an example code or give me any idea about this?

Comment: Your app does not have access to the contents of `Documents/` on Android 11+, except for files that your app placed there. Rather than create your own file-selection UI, use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.OpenDocument` for a system-supplied one that *does* work with `Documents/`.

Comment: `After creating this directory, I have write the code below` If you created a directory then that directory is empty. So i do not understand that you are listing files after that as you will certainly have a zero items list.

Comment: And what do you mean with 'a custom file path'?

Comment: @blackapps the created a folder named "App Name" inside "document". And the file path of downloaded pdf is "/storage/emulated/0/Documents/AppName/xyz.pdf". How can we show all PDFs from "App Name" folder to a recyclerView??

Comment: Uf you could react to the point to my comments first..